Calculate the number of duplicate elements in the list in Dart
I need to create a function that counts the number of duplicate items in the list, i.e. I have this list:
['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'a']

The output is the number. In this case it's 2 ('a' and 'c' come across more than once).
I suppose I can solve this task by using function forEach(). But I  don't quite understand how to use it. I will be glad to help!

You need to store the state of strings that have occurred. Hence, I'd write a separate function for clarity to handle your case:
int getAmountOfDuplicateEntries(List items) {
  Map<String, int> collectedEntries = {};

  for (var item in items) {
    int value = collectedEntries[item] ?? 0;
    collectedEntries[item] = value + 1;
  }

  collectedEntries.removeWhere((key, value) => value <= 1);

  return collectedEntries.length;
}

List myItems1 = ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'c', 'a'];
List myItems2 = ['foo', 'bar', 'foz', 'baz'];

int duplicates1 = getAmountOfDuplicateEntries(myItems1);
int duplicates2 = getAmountOfDuplicateEntries(myItems2);

In this solution, we'll track the exact amount of similar entries. After that we just remove the collected entries that have occurred only once. The length of the collection will represent the amount of duplicate ones.

For these, https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Map/update.html is more convenient.
